# How do I edit the nginx.conf for a VVV-instantiated VM?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, vagrant, vvv-wordpress

I am trying to use VVV to set up a local development environment for an existing WordPress site (hosted on WP Engine if it makes any difference) but am unable to change the `nginx.conf` to point to the correct webroot.

Following the [official documentation](https://varyingvagrantvagrants.org/docs/en-US/adding-a-new-site/adding-an-existing-site/) I have provisioned a new site using the base [custom site template](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/custom-site-template.git) then swapped it for our WordPress install and database.

This creates a site with a public_html webroot. Since our site is on Apache we have an htdocs folder instead. So, per [these instructions](https://varyingvagrantvagrants.org/docs/en-US/adding-a-new-site/custom-public_html/) I have edited `provision/vvv-nginx.conf` to change the root and have reprovisioned.

On reprovisioning, the nginx.conf gets overwritten with the original one form the custom site template.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

I have also tried sshing into the vagrant box and manually editing the config per [these instructions](https://theshipyard.se/making-changes-to-nginx-configuration-in-varying-vagrant-vagrants-without-running-a-full-provision/) but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Also: I'm not married to VVV if anyone has alternate suggestions for spinning up a VM-based WordPress environment. I just need something that can support multiple sites and is relatively easy to configure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fork the [custom site template](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/custom-site-template.git).

[Per discussion with the developers](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/issues/1723#issuecomment-457778580), the custom site template init script resets everything on each provision, including the `vvv-nginx.conf` files.

And since you need to provision to set up the VM, to change the paths you need to fork and modify the template itself. Either by editing `vvv-nginx.conf` or by modifying the behavior of `vvv-init.sh`.